# Error handling for data returned from Mongo Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, error-handling

Still a relative newbie, but  I'm using a portal to allow people to check if a person is a member of a club. I'm using mongodb and mongoose to do this, however when a number is entered that isn't in the database an error is returned "TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined" fair enough,but i'm not sure how to handle this error, please see my code below: I know there are a few ways I can refactor and tidy up my code, but it's the mongoose error handling i would like to know about. Cheers

```
app.get('/checkmembership', function(req, res) {

    var jsonResponse = {};
    var returnArray =[];

    var dbArray,
        queryArray,
        resulta,
        resultb,
        resultc,
        resultd,
        resulte,
        resultf;

    console.log("before running compareDetails " + returnArray);

    User.find({username: req.query.memberIdQuery}, function(err, foundData) {

        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            dbArray = [foundData[0].username, foundData[0].emailaddress, foundData[0].surname];
            console.log(dbArray);
            dbArray = dbArray.join('|').toLowerCase().split('|');
            console.log(dbArray);
            queryArray = [req.query.memberIdQuery, req.query.emailQuery, req.query.surnameQuery];
            console.log(queryArray);
            queryArray = queryArray.join('|').toLowerCase().split('|');
            console.log(queryArray);
            returnArray = compareDetails(queryArray, dbArray);
            resulta = returnArray[0];
            resultb = returnArray[1];
            resultc = returnArray[2];
            resultd = returnArray[3];
            resulte = returnArray[4];
            resultf = returnArray[5];
        }

        jsonResponse = { 
            set_attributes: 
            {
                resulta : resulta,
                resultb : resultb,
                resultc : resultc,
                resultd : resultd,
                resulte : resulte,
                resultf : resultf
            },
        };

        res.send(jsonResponse);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the array you getting is not empty:

Here's what you can try:

```
app.get('/checkmembership', function(req, res) {
    var jsonResponse = {};
    var returnArray =[];
    var dbArray,
        queryArray,
        resulta,
        resultb,
        resultc,
        resultd,
        resulte,
        resultf;

    console.log("before running compareDetails " + returnArray);  
        User.find({username:req.query.memberIdQuery}, function(err, foundData){
            if(err){
               console.log(err);
           } else {

            if(foundData && foundData.length) {

            dbArray = [foundData[0].username,foundData[0].emailaddress,foundData[0].surname];
            console.log(dbArray);
            dbArray = dbArray.join('|').toLowerCase().split('|');
            console.log(dbArray);
            queryArray = [req.query.memberIdQuery,req.query.emailQuery,req.query.surnameQuery];
            console.log(queryArray);
            queryArray = queryArray.join('|').toLowerCase().split('|');
            console.log(queryArray);
            returnArray = compareDetails(queryArray, dbArray);
            resulta = returnArray[0];
            resultb = returnArray[1];
            resultc = returnArray[2];
            resultd = returnArray[3];
            resulte = returnArray[4];
            resultf = returnArray[5];


            jsonResponse = { 
                set_attributes: 
                  {
                      resulta : resulta,
                      resultb : resultb,
                      resultc : resultc,
                      resultd : resultd,
                      resulte : resulte,
                      resultf : resultf
                  },
                  };
                 res.send(jsonResponse);
                } else {
                    res.send("Empty result");
                }
           }
       });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Captain Jack, also worked really well and when I saw your comment i slapped myself it made so much sense, cant believe I didn't think of it.

Comment: No worries, give it some time and you will do better!! All the best!

Answer (score 0):

> when a number is entered that isn't in the database an error is returned "TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined"

This is because, by default, when there are no matching records `foundData` will be an empty array `[]`. So, 
`foundData[0]`, technically will be an `undefined`.

> When the query is executed, the result will be an array of documents.

**Source** [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find)

To avoid this error, you can check for the size of the `foundData` before accessing it's 0th element.

Making those changes to your code.

```
app.get('/checkmembership', function (req, res) {

  let {memberIdQuery, emailQuery, surnameQuery} = req.query;

  User.find({
    username: memberIdQuery
  }, function (err, foundData) {

    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send({
        msg: `memberIdQuery = ${memberIdQuery} doesnt exist`
      });
    }

    if (!foundData || foundData.length === 0) {
      return res.status(200).send({
        msg: `No records found for memberIdQuery = ${memberIdQuery}`
      });
    }

    let dbArray = [
      foundData[0].username,
      foundData[0].emailaddress,
      foundData[0].surname
    ];
    dbArray = dbArray.join('|').toLowerCase().split('|');

    let queryArray = [
      memberIdQuery,
      emailQuery,
      surnameQuery
    ];
    queryArray = queryArray.join('|').toLowerCase().split('|');

    let [resulta, resultb, resultc, resultd, resulte, resultf] = compareDetails(queryArray, dbArray);

    return res.send({
      set_attributes: {
        resulta: resulta,
        resultb: resultb,
        resultc: resultc,
        resultd: resultd,
        resulte: resulte,
        resultf: resultf
      },
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sridhar that worked really well, and also dealt with alot of the refactoring I was planning on doing this morning 